# Subtracting two arrays (variables with decimals)

Tags: java, arrays

How to subtract the below two arrays in java?

```
(09.34, 09.56, 09.00, 08.55 )
(17.25, 18.06, 17.55, 16.00)
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the result you are expecting to get after subtracting the two arrays.

Comment: What are those?  ArrayLists?  Arrays of `float`?  Arrays of `double`?  Arrays of `BigDecimal`?  And do you mean subtract them elementwise, or some kind of set difference?  And what data type are you expecting to have at the end?

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem DOUBLE, it is so hard?

Comment: @ilw Not sure how you know what vidhu had in mind.  The question is extremely ambiguous.  The fact that they have specified numbers with trailing zeroes actually suggests this is some kind of structure of `BigDecimal`.  And the leading zeroes in the first list actually look like they were supposed to be times, rather than numbers.  But who knows?  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Substract{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double a[]={09.34, 09.56, 09.00, 08.55 };
        double  b[]={17.25, 18.06, 17.55, 16.00};
        double c[]=new double[a.length];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
           c[i]=a[i]-b[i];
           System.out.print(c[i] + "  ");
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-) How to store the subtracted value ?

Comment: you can declare a third array varaible and store it in like this ..I have modified the code

Comment: Thank you :-) worked fine for me. your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] d1 = {09.34, 09.56, 09.00, 08.55};
        double[] d2 = {17.25, 18.06, 17.55, 16.00};

        int operations = d1.length>d2.length? d2.length: d1.length;

        int noOfElements = d1.length<d2.length? d2.length: d1.length;
        double[] result = new double[noOfElements];

        for (int x=0; x<operations; x++){
            result[x] = d1[x] - d2[x];
            System.out.println(result[x]);
        }
    }
}
```